# Bootstrap Datepicker: Click on Active Date event

Tags: events, datepicker, click, bootstrap-datepicker

How can I add event when I click on active date in Bootstrap Datepicker?

dp.change does work only when I click on any different date, but not when I click on active (currently selected) date.

I tried this

```
$("#datetimepicker .active").click(function (e) {
    highlight();}
```

But it does not work.

Many thanks.